# iOS - dreaded code signing error (0xE8008016) - push notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, code-signing

Well I get this error:

1. The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing
   Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning
   profile.

   (0xE8008016).

I have checked that the bundle ID corresponds to the provisioning profile, and from what I understand, I enabled push notifications correctly for development on my app id profile (in the dev center).

Knowing that I am using push notifications, what do I need to do to resolve this?

[image]
I don't have push notifications certified for distribution, just development.

Comment: Are you using any Entitlements file in your project?

Comment: I added one recently, which didn't fix the problem. Should I be using one?

Comment: I would suggest not to use an Entitlements file. In your Build Settings and Summary, just remove off any reference to any Entitlements file and try.

Comment: Just did that, did a clean built and same error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to first create a new app ID, change the bundle ID in xCode accordingly, and do the push notifications configuration first, before creating a provisioning profile, for both development and production.

Next I created a provisioning profile with the new app ID, and changed the bundle ID in xCode, downloaded the profile, and compiled the app.

Comment: I thought app id is common to the whole account .. app id is team id right

Answer (score 0):

Not using the entitlements file - removing it from the build settings did the trick for me. (Thanks Hetal!)

Comment: I seemed to need the entitlements file per yet another StackOverflow troubleshooting tip, but this broke debugging with the dreaded 0xE8008016.  I resolved the consistency for the moment by changing the Target settings to use the file for Distribution and Ad Hoc, but deleting it for Debug and Release.      This seemed to remove the Archive option from the Action menu, but I can live with that during development.